# How to replace an url with the value of a parameter inside that URL?

Tags: php, html, regex, url, preg-replace

Like:

```
$output = preg_replace( 
    "/http\:\/\/(.*)\?mid\=([0-9|a-z|A-Z]*)/ismU", 
    "<iframe src=\"http://professional.player.qbrick.com/player.aspx?mid=${2}\"></iframe>", 
    $output 
);
```

This doesn't works...

What I want is to replace any URL in the text like

```
http://professional.player.qbrick.com/player.aspx?mid=asdas23234ASD
```

with

```
<iframe src="http://professional.player.qbrick.com/player.aspx?mid=asdas23234ASD"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you need to find or recognise the URLs in the text to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You could use sprintf to build your string instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$output = 'http://professional.player.qbrick.com/player.aspx?mid=asdas23234ASD';
$output = preg_replace( 
    "#(http://.*?\?mid=[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\b#ismU", 
    "<iframe src=\"$1\"></iframe>", 
    $output 
);
echo $output,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<iframe src="http://professional.player.qbrick.com/player.aspx?mid=asdas23234ASD"></iframe>
```